# String Values till last comma (Maximum 20 Chars) in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, regexp-substr

I have a requirement to make data in oracle as below:

Condition :- Values till last comma (Maximum 20 Chars).

```
Data                       | Length | Output
----------------------------------------------------
12,34,abc,D,eva,096,qwerty | 26     | 12,34,abc,D,eva,096
----------
12,34,abc,DEF,0014,nish    | 23     | 12,34,abc,DEF,0014
----------
12,34,abc,DEF,0014,gup,    | 23     | 12,34,abc,DEF,0014
----------
12,34,abc,D,eva            | 15     | 12,34,abc,D,eva
----------
```

I Have tried below query to get data, its giving result with comma in last and i don't know how to restrict string limit in regexp.

SELECT regexp_substr('12,34,abc,DEF,0014,nish', '(.)+,') FROM dual;

Comment: what query did you have try?

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and include the query you've tried.

Comment: Also - why is `,eva` not removed from the last line?

Comment: @BobJarvis The string is not > 20 chars

Answer (score 2):

The following will give the result you seem to be looking for, but I'm not sure it's correct as I suspect there's more to the assignment than has been mentioned:

```
SELECT LINE,
       LENGTH(LINE) AS ORIGINAL_LENGTH,
       CASE
         WHEN LENGTH(LINE) > 20 THEN
           SUBSTR(LINE, 1, INSTR(TRIM(',' FROM LINE), ',', -1)-1)
         ELSE LINE
       END AS RESULT
  FROM DATA
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d2eb6/3)

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Doesn't work for 12,34,abc,DEF,0014,gup,

Comment: I missed the trailing comma on that line in my test data. Fixed now, and SQLFiddle updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try `regexp_replace(substr(your_string||',', 1, 21), ',[^,]*$')`

Comment: @Gary_W - Thanks, fixed.